# Proof using axioms of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Using axioms of real numbers prove for
∀x∈R, ∀y∈R,∀n∈N:

---

($0 \leq x < y$ ) $\Rightarrow$ $x^n < y^n$

Any help with this? I have no idea how to even begin.

Comment: I'd begin looking what an ordered field is, and also mathematical induction.

Comment: What are the axioms relating to multiplication? Use induction on $n$ and then you can construct a sequence of inequalities with them to get the inductive step of your problem done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By induction.

Base case $n=1$,

$$0\le x < y\implies x^1<y^1.$$

Induction

$$0\le x < y\implies x^n<y^n,$$

$$0\le x < y\land x^n<y^n\implies 0\le x\,x^{n}<y\,x^{n}<y\,y^{n}.$$

Comment: I have fixed a little flaw: as $x$ can be zero, $x\,x^n<x\,y^n$ might not hold.

Answer (score 0):

It's not restrictive to assume that $x>0$, because $0^n=0$ and $y>0$ implies $y^n>0$ (do an easy induction).

The base case $n=1$ is obvious. Suppose that $x^n<y^n$. Then
$$
xx^n<xy^n
$$
and
$$
xy^n<yy^n
$$

This only uses the fact that $x<y$ and $z>0$ implies $xz<yz$.

Answer (score -1):

$$ 0 \leq x < y \implies ln(x) < ln(y) \implies k \cdot ln(x) < k \cdot ln(y) \implies x^k < y^k $$

Step 1 : The logarithm is a crecient function in $R^+$.

Step 2 : k is positive.

Step 3 : The exponential is a crecient function in $R$.

Comment: That's not a proof using the axioms of real numbers.